# Can a 1x4 jack stud be used instead of a 2x4?

Tags: safety, framing

I just noticed that my contractor,whom is building a shed, has cut the sole plate and replaced the jack stud with a 1 by 4 to accommodate a door he ordered.  He had framed the opening too small and this was solution. The door jamb fits snugly in the opening and can't be shimmed to fit properly.  Is the 1 by 4 jack stud safe or should I insist that he reframe the door properly using 2 by 4s instead.  this is a load bearing wall. It's really a 20ft by 20ft shop on a concrete slab. There are no present plans to live in it. A main concern is that the 1 x 4 untreated jack stud is contacting the concrete slab

[image: 1x4 jack stud contacting concrete slab.]

Comment: Is this a shed where someone will live?  Or is it like a woodshed with no notable roof loads, infrequent use, and light duty construction?

Comment: It's really a 20ft by 20ft shop on a concrete slab.  There are no present plans to live in it.  A main concern is that the 1 x 4 untreated jack stud is contacting the concrete slab.

Answer (score 4):

Have him re-frame it, as it almost certainly won't pass inspection.  Not sure what the code specifies in you area, but the International Residential Code is really specific as to the requirements:

> **[R603.7 Jack and king studs.](http://publicecodes.cyberregs.com/icod/irc/2012/icod_irc_2012_6_par103.htm)**
>
> The number of jack and king studs installed on each side of a header
>   shall comply with Table R603.7(1). King, jack and cripple studs shall
>   be of *the same dimension and thickness as the adjacent wall studs*.

Emphasis is mine.

Comment: If only one jack stud is required, and the construction meets code requirements then the 1x is just a trimmer. Without a broader code analysis of this small structure, there's nothing conclusive that the construction is noncompliant.

Answer (score 3):

In the United States, most building codes require a minimum dimension for wood studs in bearing walls is 2x4(nominal).

The number of jack-studs varies with the size of building, the width of the opening, and the ground snow load from 1 to many. It is common for building codes to allow the use of approved framing anchors, in lieu of jack studs when only one jack stud is required.

Typically, building codes require wood in contact with concrete or masonry to be protected.

Consult your local building code. In many places exemptions from permits and inspections does not equate to an exemption from the building codes.